# Problemas ao usar string para recursos

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um app quiz, o link é https://github.com/luisbalmant/QuickQuiz-Science.

Estou tentando usar o `getString(R.string.nome)` para migrar as strings da classe java e depois conseguir usar 2 idiomas.

Nos outros lugares eu consegui puxar as strings e está funcionando mostrando os textos quando rodo o app no celular, mas no momento que eu tento usar a string nas perguntas o app simplesmente passa a não abrir mais.

```
public class Questions {

        public String mQuestions[] = {

// Funciona
                "Pergunta número 1 xxxxxxx",

// NÃO FUNCIONA
                getString(R.string.Q1_function_insulin),

        };
```

---

**=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=//=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=**

**Atualização:**

Fiz as seguintes alterações e não funcionou:

Minha MainActivity.java:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3;

    TextView score, question;

    private Questions mQuestions;

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionsLength;

    Random r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQuestions = new Questions(this);
        mQuestionsLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;

        r = new Random();
```

Meu outro arquivo Questions.java

```js
import android.content.Context;

public class Questions extends MainActivity {

    Context context;
    public Questions(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String mQuestions[] = {

            "Pergunta número 1 xxxxxxx",
            context.getString(R.string.Q1_function_insulin),
            "Outra Pergunta número 2",

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta maneira:

```
public class Questions {

    private Context context;
    private Integer[] mQuestions = new Integer[]{R.string.Q1_function_insulin, R.string.Q2_any_name};

    public Questions(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public String get(int q_number) {
        String question = null;
        try {
            question = context.getString(mQuestions[q_number - 1]);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("Question", "Invalid question number: " + q_number);
        }
        return question;
    }
}
```

Em **OnCreate** declare a classe **Questions**:

```
Questions mQuestions = new Questions(this);
```

Obtenha as questões:

```
String question1 = mQuestions.get(1); //obtém a questão 1 e assim por diante...
```

Answer (score 0):

Na altura em que você está a usar o método `getString()` o context é nulo.

Repare que está a instanciar a classe Questions na altura da declaração.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3;

    TextView score, question;

    private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();

    private String mAnswer;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        r = new Random();
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Apesar da Activity indirectamente estender de Context, a implementação é delegada num Context que é passado ao construtor.
Como a inicialização é feita na declaração do campo,

```
private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();
```

ele é feita antes de o construtor ser executado, daí o Context ser nulo.

Para resolver crie a instância no método `onCreate()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3;

    TextView score, question;

    private Questions mQuestions;

    private String mAnswer;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQuestions = new Questions();

        r = new Random();
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela atenção. Eu tentei fazer as alterações "private Questions mQuestions;" e "mQuestions = new Questions();" Mas não obtive sucesso. Onde será que posso estar errando mais?

Comment: Se fez as alterações que eu indiquei tem de funcionar, a não ser que agora tenha um outro erro.

Answer (score 0):

As respostas já contidas pode resolver o problema, mas veja abaixo uma explicação lógica em relação ao problema.

O `getString()` é um método que está contido na classe abstrata [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). O motivo de não estar funcionando, é porque você não estende essa classe no método `Questions`.

Por exemplo, se você criar sua classe `public class Questions extends Activity`, funcionará corretamente dentro do método `onCreate`. Veja abaixo o esquema:

```
Activity
    |
    +----> extends ContextThemeWrapper
                       |
                       +----> extends ContextWrapper 
                                        |
                                        +----> extends Context
```

Como você mesmo disse, "*Nos outros lugares eu consegui puxar as strings...*", justamente porque esses "*..outros lugares..*" você está estendendo corretamente a classe que contém o método que estas a usar.

Agora a solução, existem várias, como você pode ver as respostas em sua pergunta.

Comment: Mesmo fazendo assim o problema continuará a existir se a classe Questions for instanciada na altura em que é declarada(como atributo), neste caso assim `private Questions mQuestions = new Questions(this);`. O problema é que nessa altura o context é nulo. A única solução é instanciá-la  no `onCreate()` ou em outro local após ele.

Comment: @ramaral por isso eu disse "dentro do método onCreate". =D

Comment: Sim mas nesse caso não necessita de passar o contex. A classe Questions, como é uma *inner class*(não static) da activity, tem acesso aos método do context/activity. Toda a sua explicação não se aplica nesse contexto.

Comment: @ramaral A explicação é focando porque não funcionada o método getString. Você acha desnecessário demostrar isso para o usuário?! Vou deixar a parte da solução desabilitada e depois edito numa forma mais clara.

Comment: A razão, neste caso, porque o getString() não "funciona" é porque o Context é nulo. Não é porque a classe não estender de Context ou porque não é passado um ao construtor.

Comment: @ramaral acho que as duas coisas né?!

Comment: Não não é. Veja a resposta do jefferson, é passado um context e mesmo assim não vai funcionar.

Comment: Olá ramaral e @acklay. Primeiro obrigado por todas as explicações. Eu estou iniciando o aprendizado agora e pelo que entendi aqui e lendo em alguns materiais vi que uma possível solução é instanciá-la no onCreate(), mas eu não sei como fazer isso. Tentei diversas coisas, mas como eu estou aprendendo eu leio e vou no código e "chuto" e continua dando errado. Será que não existe outra alternativa mais simples de eu de repente realocar ou refazer meu **public String mQuestions[] = {...** ?

Comment: @LuísBalmant Eu testei a classe Questions e ela funciona fazendo as alterações que mencionei na minha resposta, que mais não é do que instanciá-la no `onCreate()`. Se não funciona é porque tem agora outro erro(não testei o seu código todo). Adicione um comentário com o erro.

Comment: @ramaral, obrigado pela atenção e paciência. Não tenho certeza se consegui achar o erro mas acho que é o seguinte: *Error running Questions: The activity 'Questions' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: Adicionei em AndroidManifest.xml o seguinte: *<activity android:name=".Questions" />* e aparece uma mensagem que não tem um construtor padrão

Comment: @LuísBalmant eu acho que acabei confundindo você e bagunçando totalmente sua cabeça. É difícil até explicar por aqui. A resposta do Ramaral é a mais adequada para seu caso. Dei apenas um exemplo de como poderia funcionar estendendo a classe Activity na sua classe Questions; Tenta fazer com calma, ler um pouco mais e entender o ciclo de vida de como funcionada uma activity; conhece o conceito de  Abstração, Encapsulamento e Herança?! Tente ler um pouco mais para entender melhor. Acho que ganhará mais tempo em vez de tentar ir chutando. Daqui a pouco você vai rir das suas próprias perguntas. he

Comment: @acklay. Obrigado, vou fazer o que você recomendou. O pior foi que peguei uma outra dica e agora meu código está todo bagunçado... Tenho que entregar isso no curso que estou fazendo e tentei usar strings para poder dar suporte a 2 idiomas... Mas do jeito que está é melhor eu fazer sem strings e depois fazer isso sem chutar. Vou seguir seu conselho e ler os conceitos, pois não sei como funciona. Obrigado pela ajuda. É muito bom saber que a "galera" de programação se ajuda tanto assim. Valeu, abraço. Quando eu resolver volto aqui e posto a solução.